# React 2 random objects to appear constantly

Tags: reactjs

I'm new with react and I'm building this game which has random objects appearing from holes. If you click on good object it adds score if you click a bad one it takes score away.

I've made 1 object to appear randomly and on click it will add score plus wont appear in same position. But when I try to add second it always pops in the same place and score stops working . Here is some code

```
  clearFishes(){
for(let value in this.state){
  if (!isNaN(value)){
    this.setState({
      [value]: 'translate(0, 110%)'
    });
  }
} }

displayFishes(){
let activeFish = Math.ceil(Math.random() * 12);
if (this.state.lastFish[0] === activeFish){
  this.displayFishes();
  return;
}
this.clearFishes();
this.setState({
  [activeFish]: 'translate(0, 15%)',
  lastFish: [activeFish]
}); }



lockOutClick(){
window.setTimeout(() => {
  this.setState({ fishHasBeenClicked: false })
}, 350) }

addToScore(e){
if (this.state.fishHasBeenClicked){ return; }
let target = e.target;
target.parentNode.classList.add('game__cross');
target.classList.add('no-background');
this.lockOutClick();
this.setState({
  background: '75px',
  fishHasBeenClicked: true,
  score: [parseInt(this.state.score, 0) + 1]
});
window.setTimeout(function(){
  target.parentNode.classList.remove('game__cross');
  target.classList.remove('no-background');
}, 500)}
```

Comment: Hi and welcome to stackoverflow. I can tell straight out that yes you are unfamiliar with react. Direct DOM manipulation (even classnames) is an anti-pattern in react, and you typically don't want to place state updates within a setTimeout as the component may be unmounted when the timer expires. Can you update your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example?

Answer (score 0):

Children elements should never access parent element directly. This approach is against React philosophy. You should read a little bit more of React philosophy.

```js
target.parentNode.classList.add('game__cross');
target.classList.add('no-background');
```

Please use a method other than this direct approach. For example, storing a variable in useState.